# How to convert text from upper to lower case in main page when toggleswitch is adjusted in another page

Tags: c#, textblock, windows-phone

How to convert `textblock` text from upper to lower in main page when `toggleswitch` is clicked in another sample page?

Answer (score 1):

By page im guessing another class, im also guessing this is winForms, to do this you could have an event that the class that has the text on listens for then converts its.

example

```
//add this where you start your form
page2.radiobutton.checkedChanged += onToggle;

//this function is what listens for the change
private void onToggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(page2.radiobutton.Checked)
           textarea.text = textarea.text.tolower();
      else
            textarea.text = textarea.text.toupper();
}
```

Comment: Since it's tagged as a windows phone 7 question I doubt he needs winforms, but the logic is the same.

Comment: oh lol i didnt notice that, next time ill keep an eye on that i just read the questions didnt pay attention to the tag.  but yeah like you said same logic anyways